# overall rank working with using FIND_IN_SET but department wise not working rank query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have tried to get overall rank using FIND_IN_SET, it's working, at the same time using department_id 105 it's working.

query:SELECT id, emp_id ,emp_name, dept_id, total_pt, FIND_IN_SET( total_pt, ( SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( total_pt ORDER BY total_pt DESC )
FROM performance_score ) ) AS rank,overall_rank FROM performance_score_bk where dept_id = 105

[image]

But after i tried to get the rank with department_id 111, it'not starting with rank 1, it's starting 8 and no proper order.
Please check the inform me where i did a mistake.

query:SELECT id, emp_id ,emp_name, dept_id, total_pt, FIND_IN_SET( total_pt, ( SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( total_pt ORDER BY total_pt DESC )
FROM performance_score ) ) AS rank,overall_rank FROM performance_score_bk where dept_id = 111
[image]

Comment: Please provide query that you have tried.

Comment: I have shared my query

Answer (score 0):

Simulating rank on MySQL versions 5.7 and earlier is a real pain-in-the-neck.  If you have a long term need for rank, or other analytic functions, then consider upgrading to MySQL 8+.  In MySQL 8 we can easily write:

```
SELECT
    dept_id,
    total_pt,
    RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY dept_id ORDER BY total_pt DESC) `rank`,
    RANK() OVER (ORDER BY total_pnt DESC) overall_rank
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY
    dept_id,
    total_pt DESC;
```